# New to Ruby on Rails - Association Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to set the associations . By now I have both models Post and Comment with their associations (in theory).

The problem is that when I try to see the comment of a specific post it says that such method does not exist.

I am sure  forgetting something kinda obvious but I can't figure it out.
Thanks in advance!

MODELS

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

And i got the error on rails console:

```
p = Post.all

p[0].comments

"undefined method comments for post"
```

Controllers:

Coment:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /comments
  # GET /comments.json
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  # GET /comments/1
  # GET /comments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /comments/new
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  # GET /comments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update(comment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /comments/1
  # DELETE /comments/1.json
  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to comments_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:post_id, :body)
    end
end
```

Post:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with you associations.Please try to reload your console once and check again.

Comment: I already did that several times with reload! but still not working

Comment: Can you post some more of your code please?

Comment: Sure but what exactly, i havent done a lot much really. I created both scaffolds running these commands:   rails generate scaffold post title:string body:text/ rails generate scaffold comment title:string body:text post_id:integer body text, then i ran rake db:migrate and nothing else

Comment: what error are you getting exactly?? the same that you have mentioned above?? Please post your exact error here

Comment: Show your controller and view code please

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method 'comments for #<Post04f86060>

Comment: Try the below code that i have added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
has_many :comments, :class_name => "Comment", :foreign_key => :post_id
```

Comment: Column in database exists? Usually this is the cause of this error?

Comment: what happens when you type on your console Post.new.comments ?

Comment: The same, undefined method comments

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you're trying to pull all comments for all posts, try this in rails console. This will only pull the first Post and then its related comment.

```
p = Post.first
p.comments
```

Are you getting an error on the view as well? If so, can you post the code from the view in question.